# Remove everything after a certain string except it follows another specific string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file with these kind of entries

```
Hampton Inn New York Chelsea
Holiday Inn Express
```

I want to clean the locations after Inn unless Inn is followed by the word Express, using SED. That means I want to end up with this

```
Hampton Inn
Holiday Inn Express
```

How could I do this using sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way also

```
sed 's/\(.*Inn\) \(Express\)\?.*/\1 \2/' FileName
```

**Explanation:**

```
\(.*Inn\)       - Match the content untile Inn 
\(Express\)\?   - If the Express word match then only capture the word 
.*              - Discard all the remaining character
\1              - Print the first group until Inn
\2              - Print the second group ( If the Express word match )
```

**OutPut:**

```
Hampton Inn 
Holiday Inn Express
```

Comment: Why are you matching up to Inn ?

Comment: Yeah not the content before, no need for the .* at the start, does nothing at all, except capture more than you need..........

Answer (score 1):

If theres only one Inn per line you can do

```
sed '/Inn Express/b;s/Inn.*/Inn/' file
```

Alternatively if you want to delete things after the Express as well then you can use

*(GNU sed)*

```
sed -r 's/(Inn (Express)?).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: I understand it as the OP wants to remove anything after `Inn` unless it is followed by  `Express` in which case the second solution will always remove everything following `Inn` except `Express` perhaps `sed -r 's/(Inn (Express.*)?).*/\1/' file` might work instead?

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be:

```
sed -E "s/^(.*[[:<:]]Inn[[:>:]]( Express)?).*$/\1/" yourfile
```

I wrapped "Inn" in word boundaries to get things right.

Why?

Suppose your list is:

```
Hampton Inn New York Chelsea
Holiday Inn Express
Sample Inn of Innovative People
```

And your regexp is:

```
sed -E "s/^(.*Inn( Express)?).*$/\1/" yourfile
```

It would lead to this WRONG result:

```
Hampton Inn
Holiday Inn Express
Sample Inn of Inn
```

Comment: Good comment, very useful indeed